# How do create an overloaded operator for the form a[x][y]?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a simple Matrix class that I must read/write from in the format `a[index1][index2]`.

For example:

```
Matrix a;

a[1][2] = 5;
```

How would I implement that in C++? thanks.

Comment: A single function will be better. ie `a.get(1,2)` or `a[{1, 2}]`

Comment: @Pubby or an `operator()` with two indices, `a(1,2)`

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-array-of-array.html

Comment: but i must use this format a[1][2] = 5;:(

Comment: Why must you use that format?

Comment: What makes you think that this site's purpose was to do your homework for you?

Comment: @jork: As usual the parashift article is just wrong. You can easily write [][] as efficiently as () with only a tiny wrapper object that the compiler easily optimizes out. It is even done in such a way that it does not hinder you in choosing any internal representation you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a nice base implementation that does exactly what you want.

**Update (September 26, 2013):** I have improved the code quite a lot.

The type `T` in the template only needs to satisfy the requirements of an `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class matrix {
    class row {
        std::vector<T> values;
    public:
        row(std::size_t n)
            : values(n, T()) {}

        T& operator[] (std::size_t index) {
            if (index < values.size())
                return values[index];
            else
                throw std::domain_error("Matrix column index out of bounds.");
        }
        const T& operator[] (std::size_t index) const {
            if (index < values.size())
                return values[index];
            else
                throw std::domain_error("Matrix column index out of bounds.");
        }

        std::size_t size() const { return values.size(); }
    };

    std::vector<row> rows;

public:
    matrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n)
        : rows(m, row(n)) {}

    row& operator[](std::size_t index) {
        if (index < rows.size())
            return rows[index];
        else
            throw std::domain_error("Matrix row index out of bounds.");
    }
    const row& operator[](std::size_t index) const {
        if (index < rows.size())
            return rows[index];
        else
            throw std::domain_error("Matrix row index out of bounds.");
    }

    std::size_t row_count() const { return rows.size(); }
    std::size_t col_count() const {
        if (rows.size()) return rows[0].size();
        return 0;
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return row_count() * col_count(); }
};
```

For convenience, this helper can be used to print a matrix.

```
#include <ostream>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const matrix<T>& mat) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < mat.row_count(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0u; j < mat.col_count(); ++j) {
            o << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        o << '\n';
    }
    return o;
}
```

And just for you, a usage example to test this:

```
int main() {
    matrix<int> mat_0(2, 3);
    matrix<double> mat_1(1, 2);

    mat_0[0][0] = 2;
    mat_0[0][1] = 3;
    mat_0[0][2] = 4;
    mat_0[1][0] = 3;
    mat_0[1][1] = 7;
    mat_0[1][2] = 9;

    mat_1[0][0] = 0.43;
    mat_1[0][1] = 213.01;

    std::cout << mat_0;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << mat_1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to overload `Matrix::operator[]` so that it returns a helper class that represents a column in your matrix. That helper class should also overload `operator[]` to access an element within that column.

However, implementing it this way can be overcomplicated. Instead, it might be easier to implement `operator()` and have it take the two indices as arguments:

```
int& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j)
{
  return internal_array[i][j];
}
```

Comment: :( but i must use this format a[1][2] = 5; can you write it?

Comment: +1 The double a[x][y] is not very efficient and if you need good performance it's much better to use the a(x,y) form.

Answer (score 2):

Define a nested `class RowType` with `operator[]` returning a ref to a `Matrix` element, and define the `Matrix` `operator []` to return a ref to an elemt of `RowType`.

Here is a variation on the thema (around the first answer). I just belive you shuld not use new-delete.. ah, and a template, to use int, double, complex, (string!?) etc. This is not a full implemetation and I have not debugged it. It is just an idea.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename Num>
class Matrix {
   public:
    class RowType 
    { public:
       RowType () { }
       RowType (unsigned int columnCount):values(columnCount,Num()) {}
             int& operator[](unsigned int index)     {return values[index];}
       const int& operator[](unsigned int index)const{return values[index];}

       std::vector<Num> values;
    };

    Matrix() {  }
    Matrix(unsigned int rowCount, unsigned int columnCount)
              :rows(rowCount, MatrixRow<Num>(columnCount) )  {}
          RowType& operator[](unsigned int index)     {return rows[index]);}
    const RowType& operator[](unsigned int index)const{return rows[index]);}

  private:  std::vector<RowType<Num>> rows;
};

....
Matrix<int> a(10,10);
a[9][9]=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 1d Matrix class, e.g. `Matrix1D` and overload its `[]` operator to give you access to the value at a specific index.

Then you could create a 2d Matrix class, e.g. `Matrix2D` and overload its `[]` operator to give you access to one of the `Matrix1D` class contained in it.

That way you'd transition from `a` (`Matrix2D`) to `Matrix1D` with `[]` and then to the value with the 2nd `[]`.